# Complex Integration - where did i make the mistake?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Given function $\oint_cRezdz$ where $C$ is the unit half circle with radius $1$.

I know it's a rather simple one but I checked my work 5 times and just couldn't see it...

My attempt:

Since the function is clearly not analytic:

First contours: $$c_1: z(t)=z_0+re^{it}=1+e^{it}, t\in[0,\pi], \dot{c}_1=ie^{it} $$
$$c_2:z(t) = -1 + t, t\in[0,2], \dot{c}_2=1$$

$$\begin{align}\oint_cRezdz &=
\oint_cRe(1+e^{it})ie^{it}dt+\oint_cRe(-1+t)dt\\&=\oint_cie^{it}dt+\oint_c-1dt+\oint_ctdt\\&=e^{it}\Big|_0^\pi-t\Big|_0^2+t^2/2\Big|_0^2\\&=-1\end{align}$$

But the solution should be $\frac{\pi}{2}i$

Where did i make the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is supposed to be the part of circle with center $0$  in the upper half plane: $z=e^{i\theta}, 0<\theta<\pi$. So you get $\int_0^{\pi} \cos (\theta) ie^{i\theta} d\theta$ and the value is $\frac {\pi i} 2$.

Comment: ouhhh $e^{it}=cos(t)+isin(t)$ i ignored the $cos$ part....

Comment: But where does $z_0=1$ come from ?  $1$ is the radius, not the center of the circle. @Tomy

Comment: ouih right sorry thats another mistake